# WiFi MAC address is not available in about phone > status

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand how WiFi and bluetooth MAC address are passed to android application layer. 
In my android 8 code i can see this log

```
01-01 00:00:31.213   424   424 I SystemServiceManager: Starting com.android.server.BluetoothService
01-01 00:00:31.219   424   424 D BluetoothManagerService: Loading stored name and address
01-01 00:00:31.219   424   424 D BluetoothManagerService: Stored bluetooth Name=iMX6,Address=18:93:D7:1B:0E:E0
```

That possibly is coming from this file 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e098050/services/java/com/android/server/BluetoothManagerService.java

```
/**
     * Retrieve the Bluetooth Adapter's name and address and save it in
     * in the local cache
     */
    private void loadStoredNameAndAddress() {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "Loading stored name and address");
        if (mContext.getResources().getBoolean
            (com.android.internal.R.bool.config_bluetooth_address_validation) &&
             Settings.Secure.getInt(mContentResolver, SECURE_SETTINGS_BLUETOOTH_ADDR_VALID, 0) == 0) {
            // if the valid flag is not set, don't load the address and name
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "invalid bluetooth name and address stored");
            return;
        }
        mName = Settings.Secure.getString(mContentResolver, SECURE_SETTINGS_BLUETOOTH_NAME);
        mAddress = Settings.Secure.getString(mContentResolver, SECURE_SETTINGS_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS);
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "Stored bluetooth Name=" + mName + ",Address=" + mAddress);
    }
```

Also I can see WiFi MAC address value from,

```
cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/address
```

My confusion is when I enable wifi and blurtooth in my device I can see MAC address for bluetooth but not for wifi.

1.How java layer code know bluetooth MAC address? I don't see any .ro property for bluetooth MAC address on getprop?

2.Why java layer code is not able to get wifi mac address and shows unavailable?

3.just make me understand how that java code works? From where and how it gets the MAC address of bluetooth.

I mostly work in linux layer and I have no idea how java code is able to figure out this piece of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by below links, as I was using TI wifi+bluetooth chip,

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/WiLink8_Linux_Getting_Started_Guide

This link will provide git repos for TI's wpan and wlan. 
This repo gives C files that we can build and get lib_driver_cmd_wl12xx.a library, which are required for java > HIDL calls.

I had only ported wpan but not wlan which contain the important calls such as mac address call from wlan interface, in

```
driver_mac80211_nl.c

int wpa_driver_nl80211_driver_cmd(void *priv, char *cmd, char *buf,
                  size_t buf_len )
{
    .
    .
    linux_get_ifhwaddr(drv->global->ioctl_sock, bss->ifname, macaddr);
    .
    .
}
```

Due to this mistake in porting, my wifi calls such as

`getMac`

was failing with null and giving output string as unavailable.

After porting this repo with android O, I can build required libraries and see correct mac address in about > settings > status.